# Dual monitors in Sikuli

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script

I'm using **Sikuli** (sikulixapi-1.1.0).

I have 2 monitors. When I use my primary monitor, everything is ok. When I also use the second monitor, it does not work.

I make a screenshot on the second monitor and I wrote this:

```
Screen s = new Screen(1);
```

**Error**

> Possible cause in case you did not touch the mouse while script was
>   running:  Mouse actions are blocked generally or by the frontmost
>   application. You might try to run the SikuliX stuff as admin.

Comment: I don't know how to run SikuliX as admin. Do you have example.

Comment: Are you using the sikulix IDE?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be having issues with the multimoitor setup.

A similar question was asked on launchpad and can be found here:
 https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/295379

The basic advice was *"Make sure you are using the latest version of 1.1.1 in your java context"*